# is the process still running in docker container

Tags: python, docker, uvicorn

When I login into the python container running in Kubernetes and using this command to check the process:

```
root@chat-server-service-594dc96485-rpphl:~/chat-server# ps aux
USER       PID %CPU %MEM    VSZ   RSS TTY      STAT START   TIME COMMAND
root         1  0.0  0.2  97084 17560 ?        Ssl  17:19   0:01 python3 -m uvicorn main:app --port 8001 --host 0.0.0.0 --reload
root         8  0.0  0.0  12224  5920 ?        S    17:19   0:00 /usr/local/bin/python3 -c from multiprocessing.resource_tracker import main;main(4)
root         9  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        Z    17:19   0:01 [python3] <defunct>
root        14  0.0  0.0   4292  1504 pts/0    Ss   17:47   0:00 bash
root        65  0.0  0.0   6752  1536 pts/0    R+   17:54   0:00 ps aux
```

shows the pid 1 are listening on port 8001, but I could not access the 8001 port, shows that connection refused:

```
root@chat-server-service-594dc96485-rpphl:~/chat-server# curl http://0.0.0.0:8001
curl: (7) Failed to connect to 0.0.0.0 port 8001: Connection refused
root@chat-server-service-594dc96485-rpphl:~/chat-server# curl http://0.0.0.0:8001
curl: (7) Failed to connect to 0.0.0.0 port 8001: Connection refused
root@chat-server-service-594dc96485-rpphl:~/chat-server# curl http://0.0.0.0:8001
```

and I still could run this command in terminal:

```
root@chat-server-service-594dc96485-rpphl:~/chat-server# python3 -m uvicorn main:app --port 8001 --host 0.0.0.0 --reload
INFO:     Will watch for changes in these directories: ['/root/chat-server']
INFO:     Uvicorn running on http://0.0.0.0:8001 (Press CTRL+C to quit)
INFO:     Started reloader process [58] using WatchFiles
^CINFO:     Stopping reloader process [58]
```

is that 1 process still running? what should I do to make the startup command work. this is my docker file:

```
FROM python:3.8

LABEL example (example@gmail.com)

ENV LANG=en_US.UTF-8 \
    LC_ALL=en_US.UTF-8 \
    TZ=Asia/Shanghai

RUN ln -snf /usr/share/zoneinfo/$TZ /etc/localtime \
    && echo $TZ > /etc/timezone \
    && mkdir -p /root/chat-server 


ADD . /root/chat-server/

EXPOSE 8001

RUN pip3 install -r /root/chat-server/requirements.txt

WORKDIR /root/chat-server/
ENTRYPOINT exec python3 -m uvicorn main:app --port 8001 --host 0.0.0.0 --reload
```

I added `lsof` package and found the fastapi did not listening on this port:

```
root@chat-server-service-6f59d77848-wcj6c:~/chat-server# ps aux|grep python
root         1  0.1  0.2  97084 17784 ?        Ssl  17:27   0:00 python3 -m uvicorn main:app --port 8001 --host 0.0.0.0 --reload
root         7  0.0  0.0  12224  6852 ?        S    17:27   0:00 /usr/local/bin/python3 -c from multiprocessing.resource_tracker import main;main(4)
root         8  0.9  0.0      0     0 ?        Z    17:27   0:02 [python3] <defunct>
root        27  0.0  0.0   3236   720 pts/0    S+   17:31   0:00 grep python
root@chat-server-service-6f59d77848-wcj6c:~/chat-server# lsof -i:8001
root@chat-server-service-6f59d77848-wcj6c:~/chat-server#
```

now the problem is: the process running, but did not listening on port 8001. I also tried to pull the image to my local machine, this problem still exists.

Comment: Would `curl http://localhost:8001` also fail with `Connection refused`?

Comment: yes, the localhost also failed with connection refused

Comment: As the allocated tty of process with pid=1 is `?`, you can try `docker attach` to obtain the interface and inspect logs

Comment: From what you've shown it does seem like the listener is stopped, which is a little odd.  Is anything interesting in the `docker logs` of the container (or the `kubectl logs` of the Pod)?  If you are in a Kubernetes environment, can you set a liveness probe so the cluster restarts your Pod if this ever happens again?

Comment: I finally found the app missing some configuration, but the process should exists. so that I could know something wrong.

Comment: I fixed the configuration issue but the problem still exists, it is so wired.

Comment: Please provide a [mcve]

Comment: I'm not familiar with this syntax, but `exec` inside `ENTRYPOINT` is looking weird. Do you have any problem without `exec`? `ENTRYPOINT python3 -m uvicorn main:app --port 8001 --host 0.0.0.0 --reload`